# Solving system of equations in sympy with matrix variables

Tags: sympy

I am looking for a matrix that solves a complicated system of equations; i.e., it would be hard to flatten the equations into vector form. Here is a toy example showing the error that I'm getting:

```py
from sympy import nsolve, symbols, Inverse
from sympy.polys.polymatrix import PolyMatrix
import numpy as np
import itertools as itr

nnodes = 2
nodes = list(range(nnodes))
u_mat = PolyMatrix([symbols(f'u{i}{j}') for i, j in itr.product(nodes, nodes)]).reshape(2, 2)
u_mat_inv = Inverse(u_mat)
equations = [
    u_mat_inv[0, 0] - 1,
    u_mat_inv[0, 1] - 0,
    u_mat_inv[1, 0] - 0,
    u_mat_inv[1, 1] - 1
]
s = nsolve(equations, u_mat, np.ones(4))
```

This raises the following error:

```py
TypeError: X must be a row or a column matrix
```

Is there a way around this without having to write the equations in vector form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `nsolve` is getting confused because `u_mat` is a matrix. Passing `list(u_mat)` gives the input as expected by `nsolve`. The next problem is your choice of initial guess is a singularity of the system of equations.

You can use normal solve here though:

```
In [24]: solve(equations, list(u_mat))
Out[24]: [(1, 0, 0, 1)]
```